# Render 2 models together, with control

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 models: a text model and an image model.

```
text = object from text model
img  = object from image model
```

I want to render objects from these 2 models on my homepage, like this:

```
text
text
img
text
text
img
etc...
```

When I do this in my controller:

```
texts = Text.where("published = ?", true, :order => "created_at DESC")
images = Image.offset(rand(Image.count)).first
@posts = texts + images
```

I get objects from both, but the images are not where I want them to be. Is there a way to control where the objects from the image model appear? Something like this:

```
@posts = texts + images.after(3)
```

or

```
@posts = texts + images.every(3)
```

Thank you. I'm trying to be concise. If there is any other information I can give, I would be happy to.

Comment: the img object which comes after 2 text objects, is their a logic or as you say it can be random image. You last part of qsn actually confused me.

Comment: Yes. The object can be a random object from the image model, but I want it to display after 2 text objects. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what if the images are repeated. you can just loop through the data and create hash like

```
{1=> [imgobj,imgobj,txtobj], 2=> imgobj,imgobj,txtobj]},
```

use this hash to display data in the views.

controller action:

```
@hsh = {} 
texts.each_slice(2).each do |text|
  images = Image.offset(rand(Image.count)).first
  count = 1
  @hsh[count] = [text[0],text[1], images]
  count+=1
end
```

In View:

```
@hsh.each do |k,v|
  v.each do |u|
    u
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to think through this.